# Is the ordering of std::recursive_directory_iterator specified?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, std-filesystem

I need to traverse a directory tree in the depth-first (DFS) manner. It *looks* like `std::recursive_directory_itereator` follows that ordering on my machine, but I could not find any guarantees on that in the standard or anywhere else. Is the ordering of the entry visits guaranteed? Or even "stable" (guaranteed to be the same if, without any changes to the inspected directory tree, we execute the same code twice)?

In case where it was / wasn't specified, but that changed over the past, it would be great to know about those changes.

Comment: [Draft standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/fs.class.directory.iterator.general#8): "The order of directory entries obtained by dereferencing successive increments of a directory_iterator is unspecified." and there is nothings else specified for recursive iterators.

Comment: The order is not specified, you will have to std::sort some collection of the results based on a predicate of your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The visit order is not guaranteed in any way.

From [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator):

> The iteration order is **unspecified**, except that each directory entry is visited only once.

*(emphasis is mine)*

I assume that on a specific system the order will be stable (just an educated guess), but even that is not guaranteed.

---

**Update:**
There is a point in the specifications that is somewhat inconsistent regarding this issue:
Despite the quote above, and a similar phrasing in the [draft standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/fs.class.directory.iterator.general#8), there is the info mentioned in the [other answer by @HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78218473/is-the-ordering-of-stdrecursive-directory-iterator-specified/78219537#78219537), which implies that the implementation can in fact be only in a DFS manner (with the order in each directory still unspecified).

Answer (score 5):

It's guaranteed to be depth-first traversal. (But the file order in each individual directory is of course unspecified.)

The first hint is the existence of [`.disable_recursion_pending()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/disable_recursion_pending). It would be hard to implement for a non-DFS approach (you'd have to store an array of bools for the current directory?).

Then there's [`[fs.rec.dir.itr.members]/21`](http://eel.is/c++draft/fs.class.rec.dir.itr#fs.rec.dir.itr.members-21) that directly requires what is essentially DFS.

Comment: Interesting, +1. But isn't _"guaranteed to be depth-first traversal"_ a bit too strong ? I agree it's very likely to implement the specification in a DFS manner, but is it really guaranteed ? If so why is the explicit mention of _"The iteration order is unspecified"_ etc. as I quoted in my answer ?

Comment: @wohlstad If you look at the second link in my answer, the standard essentially requires DFS. It doesn't say "DFS", but it describes the DFS algorithm. The only thing that can vary is the file order in each directory, but it's still DFS regardless.

Comment: I read through the second link again and I am convinced that in practice it guarantees DFS.  @Fureeish since you specifically asked about DFS, this answer is more relevant for you than mine. Please make it the accepted one.